# How do I make my function specialize on a union tag?

Tags: typescript, generics, discriminated-union

I have union types `Item` and `ItemSlot` and a mapped type that maps `Item`s to `Slot`s.

```js
type WeaponSlot = "melee" | "ranged";

type ArmorSlot = "helmet" | "gloves" | "boots";

type Weapon = {
  type: "weapon";
  slot: WeaponSlot;
  damage: number;
};

type Armor = {
  type: "armor";
  slot: ArmorSlot;
  armorValue: number;
};

type Item = Weapon | Armor;

type ItemSlot = WeaponSlot | ArmorSlot;

// type ItemSlots = {
//     melee: Weapon;
//     ranged: Weapon;
//     helmet: Armor;
//     gloves: Armor;
//     boots: Armor;
// }
type ItemSlots = {
  [O in Item as O["slot"]]: O;
};
```

There is a clear relation between items and item slots, and this is reflected in the type mapping. But I couldn't figure out how to make use of this relationship so I can make generic functions that can get an `Item` and map it to the correct `ItemSlot` in a type safe way.

These work

```js
// manual way
function putItem(item: Item, slots: ItemSlots) {
  if (item.slot === "boots") {
    slots["boots"] = item;
  } else if (item.slot === "melee") {
    slots["melee"] = item;
  }
}


// can do generic when slot is passed from outside
function putItem2<S extends ItemSlot>(
  item: ItemSlots[S],
  slots: ItemSlots,
  slot: S,
) {
  slots[slot] = item;
}
```

But I don't want the manual option. And slot may not get passed from outside like examples below

```js
// a function that takes an item and puts it in its corresponding slot
function putItem3(item: Item, slots: ItemSlots) {
  slots[item.slot] = item;
}

// or a function that takes an item list and slot as an input and
// filters items to get an item suitable for the slot
function putItem4(items: Item[], slot: ItemSlot, slots: ItemSlots) {
  // just return the first item that suits to slot
  const item = items.filter((item): item is Something => item.slot === slot)[0];

  slots[item.slot] = item;
}
```

Somehow I need to hint that the item has a slot that would point to one of the correct slots. Do I need to make `Item` generic on `Slot`? How would that work together with union types? Or is there a better solution maybe that doesn't require the use of more generics?

This doesn't seem like a unique problem. I would also appreciate if you can link some examples in the wild where union types are handled in a generic way.

Comment: This is essentially [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the supported approach is a specific sort of generic refactoring as described at [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). If I use that here, I get [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WPOvKm). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: This solves my problem, so you can write up the answer. Thank you for the reading materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into an issue I've called "correlated union types", as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  Sometimes people write code where an unchanging value of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) is used multiple times, and which is clearly safe if you keep in mind that the value's type must be the same union member in all occurrences.  For example, if `x` is of type `number[] | string[]`, then `x.push(x[0])` is safe (assuming `x` is non-empty) because `x` is either a `number[]` both times or it's a `string[]` both times.  But the compiler does not analyze the code this way because it's not tracking the *identity* of the value, just the type.  It treats it the same as if you wrote `x1.push(x2[0])` where both `x1` and `x2` are of type `number[] | string[]`.  And that would clearly be *unsafe*.

That's the problem you're having with your `putItem()` code. `slots[item.slot]` and `item` must be of the same type, but that's only discoverable if you tract the *identity* of `item` and not its type.

---

The recommended approach to correlated unions is a refactoring described at [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), where you move away from unions and toward [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) that are [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to unions, and specifically involving a "base" interface and generic [indexes into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that interface and into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that interface.  The goal is to make it so that the two correlated expressions are seen as being of a visibly-equivalent *generic* type.

With your example as shown, it could look like this.  First the base interface:

```
type ItemMap = { [I in Item as I["type"]]: I }
/* type ItemMap = {
    weapon: Weapon;
    armor: Armor;
} */
```

And then the `ItemSlots` type becomes a generic type of the following form:

```
type ItemSlots<K extends keyof ItemMap> = Record<ItemMap[K]["slot"], ItemMap[K]>;
```

You could keep around your original `ItemSlots` is you want, but the point of this is that `ItemSlots<"weapon">` is seen is the `Weapon`-appropriate piece of `ItemSlots`, and `ItemSlotes<"armor">` is the `Armor`-appropriate piece.

Then `putItem()` can be made generic in the following way:

```
function putItem3<K extends keyof ItemMap>(item: ItemMap[K], slots: ItemSlots<K>) {
  const slot: ItemMap[K]['slot'] = item.slot
  slots[slot] = item;
}
```

Note that there's a bit of a workaround to [microsoft/TypeScript#33181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181) since when you index into a generic (like `ItemMap[K]`) with a specific key (like `"slot"`) the compiler widens things to a non-generic.  So I needed to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) that `slot` is of type `ItemMap[K]['slot']`, since that is the key of `ItemSlots<K>`.

Your `filter()` version is similarly generic:

```
function putItem4<K extends keyof ItemMap>(
  items: Item[], slot: ItemMap[K]["slot"], slots: ItemSlots<K>
) {
  const item = items.filter((item): item is ItemMap[K] => item.slot === slot)[0];
  slots[slot] = item;
}
```

---

So that works and is at least vaguely type safe, especially compared to just using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).   It would be nice if the compiler could always "see" the safety by distributing its analysis over unions, or tracking identities, but for now microsoft/TypeScript#47109 is the best approach we have for this sort of issue.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6hCGYD2A7AygGycKBeKARALYQYQQFQA+hATvCgOYQAmBA3AFCeiRQCCtIklqZseQgAtSJYJRoFGWAG4QAzvMIAjJNg1ce4aHESoJAb05QovCAC5CAdwTIUHK1DVZgDk67HAXNYs8ETwzA4oAK5EWhC0XAC+BrYCQiIWHrYOBPDptO7WXtgOgsKi3kFQeeUAavAYUfZQ0bHxSSlGUACSwBBEEn5mNGUinXy9-QCyiBZQANrdUACWKD19A-BqPfMEtgQAugcOS4mcAPQAVDZdk0QzYJnW1s6mKL4uqFXWNSKl+UkoJdztxUncAmoADwAaSgEAAHn0UCxtgBrCAgJAAM3W00QAD4JAAlCAAYxELEhdwe82hB12xTkBwANLj7ohaQd8QYsVEUKTgMszGAosA7gBmGFwxEQZFojHYtkPfEACmWGxOGxpdNZjLUmv6EJh+IAlFBLNZySg1DhGQb2WBOfMAOSM50HCTq-oAOkZHj180ZHvwXqISW4vP5guForuABYpQikSioOjMTjqQS1Rt9Wz5izPN57dr6QRGYddd5c+Cq8azRaoFabSsNp6c96scsMH1aCrs-0TQ5QyttpnHXS8ITQ77vHhcPhGSb5gAGA5VANBtv9cNAA)